# How do I make Outlook download images automatically/by default

Tags: macos, ms-office

Outlook currently puts a banner at the top of my emails asking me for permission to download images.

How do I make it download this automatically and not ask me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Outlook Mail Settings

- Go to **Preferences...** <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> in **Outlook**
- Select **Reading** under **Email**
- The **Security** settings allow you change "Automatically download pictures from the Internet:"

  - In all messages
  - In messages from my contacts
  - Never

The default is never, that is why the 'banner' appears.  Change it to one of the other options based on your preferred usage.

---

[image: Outlook Settings]

Comment: If we choose "In messages from my contacts" is there a way to whitelist certain domains? The email address from some systems changes with each email but the domain is the same.